# Why does assigning a hex value give big-endian equivalent value on a little-endian machine?

Tags: c, endianness

Here is a simple c statement:

```
uint32_t x = 0x04000000;
```

On my little endian machine I assumed x would equal 4. But instead it's 67108864.

So there must be something very basic that I don't understand. Could you help explain please?

Comment: Can you imagine how confusing it would be if `uint32_t x = 0x00000004` sometimes represented 4 and sometimes 67108864, depending on what kind of machine you were on?

Comment: A slightly different question, for C++ instead of C, but which explains the issue perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551167/what-is-the-endianness-of-binary-literals-in-c14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint32_t x = 0x04000000;
```

This operation is machine endianness agnostic. `0x04000000` is a hex literal with the value `67'108'864` (decimal). This is true on any endianness.

If you want to see the effects of endianness systems you need to fiddle with the underlying memory. E.g.:

```
uint32_t x;
memcpy(&x,  (const unsigned char[4]) {0x04u, 0, 0, 0}, 4);
```

Comment: Why is the `u` necessary?

Comment: Also, if you were to copy just a single byte into the `uint32_t`, would you be able to tell if that would go to the LSB or MSB?

Comment: It makes the literal an unsigned literal. Good practice and force of habit. Dependable how you write it. Can't tell you without seeing your code

Answer (score 6):

When you do an assignment to a variable, you're setting the *value*, not the *representation*.

The hexadecimal number 0x04000000 is the same as the decimal number 67108864 so that is what gets assigned.  The fact that the number is represented in hex doesn't change how the assignment works.

If you did something like this:

```
unsigned char n[4] = "\x4\x0\x0\x0";
memcpy(&x, n, sizeof(x));
```

Then `x` would contain the value 4 on a little-endian machine.

Answer (score 3):

The literal `0x04000000` means the number 67108864. It will be stored differently in memory depending on whether little-endian or big-endian byte order is used, but that doesn't change its value.