# Binary values, bit-shifts and endianness

Tags: c++, serialization, endianness

I am following through a video-tutorial on serialization.
In the video, the author has created an `std::vector<int8_t>` to which he is writing values of variables of integral types **byte by byte**.

So if we take an `int32_t` variable, it will take 4 elements of that vector. The way he is doing it is by shifting the binary value of this variable by a corresponding number of bits. I understand why this is done. If we take the value `76745`, for example, the vector values will look like {0, 1, 43, -55}.

Here is the method with a little simplification from my side:

```
template <typename T>
void encode(std::vector<int8_t> *buffer, int16_t *iterator, T value)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T); ++i)
    {
        (*buffer)[(*iterator)++] = value >> ((sizeof(T) * 8 - 8) - i*8); 
    }
}
```

Now, my concern is, that he claims we need to do this in order to convert the number to little endian. I don't think it's the case, because from what I understand, endianness is how numbers are
represented in memory. When we are operating on a value with, e.g., bit-shifts, we are operating on the binary value, so it has nothing to do with endianness, just like I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184789/does-bit-shift-depend-on-endianness).

He proceeds to give a piece of code to test, as he claims, whether the machine is little-endian:

```
bool IsLittleEndian() // weirdest
{
    int8_t a = 5;
    std::string res = std::bitset<8>(a).to_string();
    std::cout << res << '\n';
    return (res.back() == '1');
}
```

This again makes me doubt, because from what I read, `bitset` is not dependent on endianness. (Additionally, if the last bit of 5 is 1, then it should be big-endian, so I am sure a confusion occurred on his side.)

Can someone confirm whether my understanding is correct? I will gladly answer any clarifying questions.

His other content is of high quality, so I would really like to continue with the tutorial, but I need to have this figured out.

Comment: 5 is an odd number - the rightmost bit of it must therefore be 1. i don't see what this has to do with endianness. perhaps this tutorial is not as good as you thought?

Comment: endianness is about _byte_ ordering. The bogus `IsLittleEndian()` is only looking at the low _bit_ of a single byte. No way to get information about _byte_ ordering from that.

Comment: Why is `buffer` a pointer? That implies that you may want to send in a `nullptr` to the function, but you never check if it's a `nullptr` or not.

Comment: Sidenote, C++20 provides a way to find out the endianness of the system through [`std::endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian)

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct: endianness has nothing to with arithmetic operations and `bitset::to_string()`. Both work in exactly the same way regardless of the underlying implementation details, and there is no "bit endianness" at all, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27551217/767632). You may run your code on a [ternary Soviet computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setun) for all that, and the behavior of the program will be the same.

What endianness *does* affect in C++ is implementation-defined stuff like memory layout and byte representation. One can exploit that to use `std::memcpy` and `reinterpret_cast` to efficiently (de)serialize integers. Be wary [of the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237004/strict-aliasing-rule-uint8-t-buffer-to-structure), though, if you want somewhat more portability in theory.

One could say that the `encode` function translates an integer into an array of bytes in a little-endian way: lower bytes have lower addresses, and that this happens regardless of the endianness of the underlying system. That may be useful when you want the same serialization protocol on different systems.

However, it's still not what the `encode` function does: it stores the highest byte in the lower address, etc. So it's actually encoding the `value` in a big-endian way.

Answer (score 1):

The first part somewhat makes sense.  The second part not so much.

If you were to simply `std::copy` the bytes of your `value` into `buffer`, i.e.

```
template <typename T>
void encode(std::vector<uint8_t>& buffer, size_t& position, T value)
{
    uint8_t* bytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&value);
    std::copy(bytes, bytes + sizeof(value), &buffer[position]);
    position += sizeof(T);
}
```

You would end up with `buffer` containing the bytes of `value` in whatever order the platform uses.  That is, `encode(buffer, n, 0x01020304)` would result in `buffer` containing `{0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01}` on little-endian systems and `{0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04}` on big-endian systems.

Using bit shifts to extract each byte of the value side-steps this issue since bit shift operations don't reflect platform endianness.  `n & 0xFF` will always give you the least-significant byte of `n`, `(n >> 8) & 0xFF` the next most significant, and so on.

---

The second part makes no sense at all though.  That `IsLittleEndian` function is nonsense.  Endianness is *byte order*, not *bit order*.  An `int8_t`, being only one byte, will never tell you anything about the platform's endianness.